# Problem to Install CentOS 6.4 (Second) after that Win7 (First) - dual boot

Tags: centos, partition, windows, dual-boot

I want to install CentOS 6.4 in my PC, this image shows my *Windows 7* partition before to install it

[image]

But when I was ask to select my option (mode) of install CentOs like this:
[image]
Or this (really is my first option):
[image]

I have this message: **Error Partitioning**
*Could not find enough free space for automatic partitioning, please use another partitioning method.*

[image]

According to CentOS my HD is like:
[image]

**How Can I solve this?**

Comment: From what I recall, dual boot with Windows *Dynamic Disk* has always been problematic. You might try reverting to *Basic Disk* before attempting to install CentOS.

Comment: Thank you, "Basic Disk" means format all Disk?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily means formatting. I'm not quite sure but certain versions of Windows might allow you to go back from dynamic to basic.

Comment: I changed this with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYVOtwsukEQ
www.mediafire.com/download/285a2aot60ohod0/Partition+Wizard.rar

Comment: Now you should be able to install CentOS normally. Don't hesitate to post how it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

```
You will require to select the last option as "CREATE CUSTOM LAYOUT".
Then create 3 patitions as follows {(mount point,file-system,size)}
a.{(/boot,ext4,256MB)}
b.{(NA,swap area,(2 x size of ram))} ===> ideal
c.{(/,ext4,(according to your storage requirement- 30-40GB)}
```

You can also refer this link
http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=install

Answer (score 0):

***sorry but having no possibility to comment I will put what I think as an answer.***

A little reading over images made me think that you have resized original windows partition and for some reason the resizing process was unsuccessful concluded or something like that. Maybe something was not written correctly and centos installation process is not able to understood the correct HDD layout (I do not think but it could be a BUG) ... he sees the fourth partition (sda4) large as it was at origin.

But what is most strange for me is: why there are two unallocated partitions next to each other? it should be only one continuous unallocated disk space.

What you can do? ...

1. if not already do backup of all your data :)
2. you should try to understand why there are two portions of unallocated space one next to other
3. try to repeat resize process (if there was one) by increasing or decreasing windows disk D: by few megabytes maybe this time it will do all right?
4. try to allocate unallocated space and create a new partition, you may try to format it, maybe after you will be able to see it during installation process as sda5 and you will be able to manipulate that partition manually to create a new one for the new OS.

Comment: Thank you, (Volume D + unallocated) seems to be interpreted like sda4.
And I don't know how to join two unallocated spaces...

Comment: There is always a bit of unallocated space that Windows creates at the end of the disk upon installation. As far as I went I wasted more energy to get rid of it than keep it. In general the "lost" space is not large enough to bother with. I think there must be some good reasons it's there but never investigated further.

Answer (score -1):

I think that before using free space you may need to change ntfs format.Because ntfs format allow only in windows OS.so change the partition format for unallocated or space where you want to keep linux files after changing partition format. Then try.